# Proper way of hiding very sensitive credentials in a web application

Tags: java, spring, security, credentials, password-protection

I am currently developing a spring boot web application. It is a REST api proxy that connects to another api using some very sensitive credentials. The credentials are hard-coded at the moment, but obviously they should not be. What is the proper way of hiding them?

I have considered using some library, like *jasypt* to encode them and put the encoded values in a properties file, with the key hidden somewhere, perhaps in system variable, (but it is just another layer of obfuscation, isn't it?)

How can I properly hide these sensitive credentials?

Comment: Yes, you can use a private key to encrype and decrype the sensitive data.

Comment: Are you trying to hide them whilst sending the credentials over? In that case you should use SSL.

Comment: If they are very sensitive use a HSM (Host Security Module) to store them.

Comment: Implement SSL which would do the job of encryption & decryption automatically.

Comment: @Henry - actually HARDWARE Security Module.  The security critical information is not stored on the host.  It is stored on a separate hardware model that is (typically) resistant to all forms of tampering ... including physical.

Comment: @StephenC You are right, this is the more common term. But occasionally you also find the other, e.g.: https://www.2-sec.com/2014/01/host-security-module-pci-dss-3-5-2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use your server environment to hide your properties. Just store on your production server application.properties with real credentials and protect access, so only your application will have access to the property file.

Comment: This works as long as you trust the persons with root access or with physical access to the server.

Comment: @Henry you should trust this persons, otherwise you are in big trouble

Comment: In high security environments you always make sure that several people (e.g. 3) need to cooperate in order to compromise a secret. Keep in mind that fraud is often an insider job.

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental problem is that if you ever need to hold security credentials *in the clear* in the memory of a computer program, AND there are people who have the equivalent of "root" access to the machine, then it is possible for one of those people to gain access to the credentials.

So you need to design your security so that that the credentials never need to be held in the server's memory.

If you are really serious about solving this, you need to investigate [Hardware Security Modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module).  However, the HSM approach is going to be complicated and expensive, and may require you to rework your authentication protocols.